# How to use Substring_Index in update statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Using Mysql Sql, How do I update an a table where the field values in "ON" clause 
dont match. The order in old table has a few extra letters. The code runs, but the 
quantity does not update. Maybe I could concatenate order??

```
UPDATE t.filled n JOIN t.open o ON n.item = o.item AND n.order = o.order  
SET o.Quantity = o.Quantity + n.Quantity WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(n.order,":",-1) = "CLD" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to `concat` one of the `x.order` to match the other, thus dropping the 
`where` clause.